# Name and Time in SharedPreference?

Tags: android, database, eclipse

Im new in android eclipse programming and I wanted to add a database that will hold the inputed name of the player and the time it tooks to finish the game and display on the highscore module. is it possile? can anyone guide me on this one? thanks for any suggestion and please be good on me guys. thanks alot.

**UPDATE** When the game finish there will be a alert dialog that will ask to enter the name. 
heres my code.

```
    private Dialog createHighScoreNameDialog() {
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.high_score_name_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    Button okButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.high_score_name_ok_button);
    final SharedPreferences preferences =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    String oldPlayersName = preferences.getString("players_name", "");

    EditText playersNameEditText = (EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.players_name);
    playersNameEditText.setText(oldPlayersName);

    okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    String playerName = ((EditText) dialog.findViewById(R.id.players_name))
                                            .getText().toString();
                }
            });
    return dialog;
```

After that what should I do to save the `playerName` on the database?

Comment: *I already have my timer and I already know how to convert it on string.* then what you want now.? Please explain actual requirement properly

Comment: You can set your High score in local Database SharedPreferences.

Any value convert in string use String.valueOf(HERE_YOUR_VALUE).

Comment: @SilentKiller sir I just want to save the time and the name of the player on a database and display it on a high scores.

Comment: @user3698267 if your values won't be large in the size so you can store it in `SharedPreferances` else you need to use `SQLite Database`

Comment: I want to set 10 highscores on the database. The `player's name` and the `time` that it tooks to finish the game will be display. is it large enough?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code given below to save any number of score and retrieve them. Create a new database helper class named, DatabaseHandler.java and add the following code in it.

To initialise the class in your activity, put the following line in your activity :

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
```

Then to add value to db use, `db.addScore(count);`

To filter out just top ten scores from the db, u may change the query in get method to :

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + "LIMIT 10";
```

.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "game";

    // Table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score";

    // Score Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID_SCORE = "_id";
    private static final String KEY_SCORE = "score_value";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_SCORE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
                + KEY_ID_SCORE + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + KEY_SCORE + " TEXT" + ")";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_SCORE_TABLE);

    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    // Adding new score
    public void addScore(int score) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(KEY_SCORE, score); // score value

        // Inserting Values
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);

        db.close();

    }

    // Getting All Scores
    public String[] getAllScores() {

        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        int i = 0;

        String[] data = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

            data[i] = cursor.getString(1);

            i = i++;

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return score array
        return data;
    }}
```

Add one more field name in table score, and you can then save name also along with score by passing it as a parameter while adding score..

Comment: thanks sir ! But how can I make a method that will compare every score? The shortest one will be remain and the longest time will be deleted among 10 scores?

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve?

Comment: please see the above update on my question. I want to have a highscore module that will display the time and the player's name. and also the rankings of every player base on how long they finish the game

Comment: You can insert any number of scores based on the above code I have provided. TO get only top 10 scores, retrieve the scores and sort them in Ascending order and get the ten values out of list. Its as simple as this. What is your issue here?